# brew doctor complains unexpected dylibs '/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib', deletable?

Tags: homebrew

I ran brew doctor and it complains unexpected dylibs '/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib'.  Is it deletable?

```
$ brew doctor                                                                                                       
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib
```

In general, how does one determine if an 'unexpected dylibs' 'brew doctor' deports is deletable?

Comment: Don't install anything except through Homebrew /usr/local.bin is the standard place that Unix builds will put executables that are  not part of the base system so you have to check eh build you do to chnage the default to be elsewhere

Comment: you know the files that the NSA place on everyone's computers while the surf the net....

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic link file you see has been installed by something else, not homebrew. That's why it is "unexpected".

Unless you are having a problem installing something with homebrew the best thing to do is ignore it.

It's not easy (perhaps impossible) to know what may have put the file there or needs it there to run.